# Create instance of a class that has array members

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to make an instance of this object with no luck , i know its because of the array but how can i make it work with the array ?

```
public class City {
    private String Country_Name;
    private String [] Cities ;
    private String [] Destinations;}

    public City(String Country_Name, String [] Cities, String [] Destinations) {
        this.Country_Name = Country_Name;
        this.Cities = new String [2];
        this.Destinations = new String [2];
    }

    public class ASSIGNMENT {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        LinkedList<FLIGHT> ob1 = new LinkedList<FLIGHT>();
        LinkedList<FLIGHT_BOOKING> ob = new LinkedList<FLIGHT_BOOKING>();
        LinkedList<City> ob3 = new LinkedList<City>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        FLIGHT_BOOKING obj = new FLIGHT_BOOKING();
        FLIGHT obj1 = new FLIGHT();
        City c1 = new City("Malaysia","Kuala","Johor","melaka"},{"Cyberjaya","Putrajaya","Sunway"});
    }
}
```

Comment: **Compile error** because `}` at end of line `private String [] Destinations;`

Comment: "*I am trying to make an instance of this object with no luck*" - What does that mean? Does the program not compile? Does it throw some kind of `Exception`? Please include the compiler error and/or exception in your question. Some remarks on your code: variable-, field- and parameter names should always start with a lowercase letter and should be written in [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) --- The `[]` are normally written after the type, without a blank (`String []` -> `String[]`).

Comment: What is `new City("Malaysia","Kuala","Johor","melaka"},{"Cyberjaya","Putrajaya","Sunway"})` supposed to do? It's a **compile error**. Did you mean `new City("Malaysia", new String[] { "Kuala", "Johor", "melaka" }, new String[] { "Cyberjaya", "Putrajaya", "Sunway" })`?

Comment: *FYI:* Class names should be mixed-case, i.e. `Assignment`, `Flight`, `FlightBooking`.

Comment: I'm trying to create a class that store a country name that has three different cities , my question is how can i pass an array in an object instance ?

Comment: And sorry for the assignment part but i just posted part of my code , forgot to remove the other codes

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced curly brace, you closed class definition before the constructor. It should be as follows:

```
public class City {
    private String Country_Name;
    private String [] Cities ;
    private String [] Destinations;

    public City(String Country_Name, String[] Cities, String[] Destinations) {
        this.Country_Name = Country_Name;
        this.Cities = new String [2];
        this.Destinations = new String [2];
    }
}
```

Also, You missed opening curly brace. Create the object as follows:

```
String[] cities = {"Kuala","Johor"}; // Giving only 2 cities as in constructor you've given as new String[2]
String[] destinations = {"Cyberjaya","Putrajaya"}; // Same as above
City c1 = new City("Malaysia", cities, destinations);
```

If you want more cities and destinations, update your constructor as

```
public City(String Country_Name, String[] Cities, String[] Destinations) {
            this.Country_Name = Country_Name;
            this.Cities = Cities;
            this.Destinations = Destinations;
        }
```